# Application Insight integration with WebJobs - Cannot override cloud_RoleInstance

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights

I'm integrating application insights with my App service which has a WebJobs project, [following these instructions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Application-Insights-Integration).

Things are working smoothly except that the cloud_RoleName and cloud_RoleInstanceName in ai portal are not meaningful (random numeric values, and seem to be changing over time).
I used a custom TelemetryInitializer in the api role, and it is changing those values as desired. However the webjob project doesn't seem to be picking up the role names assigned in custom initializer. When debugging locally, the code does execute the custom initializer overriden values, but it seems that it is being changed when the log is being sent to ai.

Here is the custom initializer that I use:

```
public class AppInsightsTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnvironmentName"];
        telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance = $"webjob-{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InstanceId"]}";
    }
}
```

And it's hooked in WebJobs' Program.cs:

```
...
ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AppInsightsTelemetryInitializer());
...
```

Could someone help me with this?
Thanks,

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it as an answer that will help more communities who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

> However the webjob project doesn't seem to be picking up the role names assigned in custom initializer.Could someone help me with this?

It should work correctly integration Azure Webjob, I test it on my side. Please have a try to get the log with [Application Insight Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-tour).

[image]